# Convert To_TimeStamp function to java

Tags: java, oracle, date

```
package testOnly;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Tests {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Tests test = new Tests();
        String s = "8/24/2015 3:09:51.000000 AM"; 
        String s2 = "fmMMfm/fmDDfm/YYYY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM";
        test.to_timestamp(s, s2);
    }

    Timestamp to_timestamp(String dateText, String oraclePattern) throws Exception {
        String javaDatePattern = null;
        if (oraclePattern.equals("fmMMfm/fmDDfm/YYYY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM")) {
            javaDatePattern = "MM-dd-yyyy HH.mm.ss.SS a";
        }
        if (javaDatePattern==null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled oracle date pattern");
        }

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(javaDatePattern);

        Date date= sdf.parse(dateText);
        return new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    }
}
//Sample data 
//TO_TIMESTAMP('8/24/2015 3:09:51.000000 AM','fmMMfm/fmDDfm/YYYY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM')
```

So in oracle there are function like To_Date, To_TimeStamp etc. I wanted to convert the oracle style to java simpleDateFormat however I keep getting unparsable date error I was wondering if anyone able to see what I cannot see.

Comment: Why? Is there a reason for you to keep around time stamp *strings* instead of actual Date objects? Also please note that the `oraclePattern` parameter in your method is just serving as a flag and there's no use of it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

There is problem in your java date format and your date input they dont match so java is unable to parse. Like you specify "-" date separator in format and providing date with "/" same with time separator. Try code below it will parse the date

---

```
    import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Tests {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Tests test = new Tests();
        String s = "8/24/2015 3:09:51.000000 AM"; 
        String s2 = "fmMMfm/fmDDfm/YYYY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM";
        test.to_timestamp(s, s2);
    }

    Timestamp to_timestamp(String dateText, String oraclePattern) throws Exception {
        String javaDatePattern = null;
        if (oraclePattern.equals("fmMMfm/fmDDfm/YYYY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM")) {
            javaDatePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS a";
        }
        if (javaDatePattern==null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled oracle date pattern");
        }

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(javaDatePattern);

        Date date= sdf.parse(dateText);
        return new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    }
}
```